# How to link to a Weather Site (direct URL)

Tags: html, weather-api

I don't see how the original question was off topic, but edited anyway...

My Problem:

I have a webite that shows an upcoming event in, say, Seattle WA.  I want to provide a handy link `<a href="someURL">` to bring up an interactive weather page for Seattle.  I do NOT want a JSON REST API etc.  I want to be able to go something like:

```
<a href="www.someweather.com/api/Seattle+WA">See Weather</a>
```

However such a URL doesn't seem to exist.  Most of the weather services (e.g. Yahoo, WeatherUnderground) allow a user to enter a city name *interactively*, but then they go through some internal magic and the URL ends up being encoded with a special ID at the end.

e.g.  Seattle WA is, respectively,

```
http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=zmw:98101.1.99999  or
http://weather.yahoo.com/united-states/washington/seattle-2490383/
http://www.weather.com/weather/today/Seattle+WA+USWA0395:1:US
```

1. Is there an Weather URL that takes a City directly?  That would be the simplest.
2. If not, does anybody know an API or method where I could translate between a City and get that magic code (e.g., for yahoo, seattle-2490383) for one of the major services?  e.g. I could go something like

   http://www.blah/weathertranslator?location=Seattle+WA&format=json

and get back the magic number (e.g. "seattle-2490383" for Yahoo)

NOTE: after more research, looks like http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?query=Seattle+WA  will do what I want for #2 for weatherunderground...

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to fight `HTML5 Geolocation`s? http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: Doesn't a link like http://www.weather.com/weather/today/SEA:9 work (no internal magic I can see)?

Comment: Yes, but how do I go from "Seattle, WA" to "SEA"?